# Is it possible to add `static ` type to gridview binding method in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

here I have one image tag when i click image i need to display data in grid view here i am calling .cs method from javascript when i take method to `static` in bind grid view it shows error message.

```
[WebMethod]
    public static void BindHeader() 

    {
        Grdview.Visible = true;
        Grdview.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        Grdview.DataBind();
    }
```

Error

> `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property '_Default.Grdview'`

Comment: This will never work. Grdview and databinding need a full page lifecycle that isn't available via a call to the webmethod. You have to redesign your approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically/programmatically build the GridView control. Then in your WebMethod, you can call RenderControl() method to retrieve the HTML content of the rendered GridView control. Return that content from the WebMethod and have the callback JavaScript function inject the HTML content into your placeholder element's innerHTML property.

Another option is to do your data binding on the client-side. So all the WebMethod has to do is pass back the data (excluding presentational markup), for example in a JSON-type format. Then you can use something like javascript templates to render the grid with data. This approach takes GridView control completely out of the picture, but depending on your needs, it may be a viable option.

Comment: you can call webservice on client to retrieve the data. In the callback function of webservice, you can bind on gridview by using javascript.

Check this: http://forums.asp.net/t/1422932.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can not access any control in `static` method as every control is an instance. If you want to bind grid view by this method, you better return string from `WebMethod` and create grid view on `success` handler of `Ajax` request.